# SQL Server Scalar Function with "IN" Getting Subquery Returned more than 1 Error

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here's the query which works well:

```
select MIN(dbo.GetDiscountedPrice(P.AutoID))
FROM Product P
where P.AutoID in (2910,2912,2820)
```

It returns the cheapest price among 2910,2912 and 2820 (AutoID is the primary key)

BUT this query returns an error:

```
select MIN(dbo.GetDiscountedPrice(P.AutoID))
FROM Product P
where P.AutoID in (SELECT AutoID FROM Product WHERE Category=2)
```

Error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

This query actually returns 2910,2912,2820

```
SELECT AutoID FROM Product WHERE Category=2
```

Why is that so and how can I achieve the purpose with by getting products based on category?

Function `GetDiscountedPrice`:

It's just a very simple function which:

1. Gets the price
2. Gets the percentage
3. Returns the discounted price after minus off the percentage

Note that percentage was taken from another table called `ProductDiscount`.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetDiscountedPrice]
(
    @ProductAutoID bigint
)
RETURNS decimal(10,4)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result decimal(10,4)   

    Declare @Price float = (select Price 
                            from Product 
                            where AutoID = @ProductAutoID)

    Declare @DP float = ISNULL
    (
        (select DiscountPercentage 
         from ProductDiscount 
         where Product_AutoID = @ProductAutoID), 0)

    set @Result = @Price - (@Price * 0.01 * @DP)

    RETURN @Result
END
```

Comment: Why do you not use query like this: `select MIN(dbo.GetDiscountedPrice(P.AutoID))
FROM Product P
where P.Category=2` ?

Comment: @VladimirSemashkin Coz it got the same error

Comment: Can you post the code of the dbo,GetDiscountedPrice function?  My guess is that the execution plan is different between the two queries such that the function is actually invoked for values besides those listed, and at least one of those values results in this error inside a function subquery.

Comment: The problem is in your function. This `where P.AutoID in (SELECT AutoID FROM Product WHERE Category=2)` and this `where P.AutoID in (2910,2912,2820)` are definitely not the same sets.  You say that they are the same and I don't believe that

Comment: I played and both queries works. Do you still have problem? How can I reproduce the problem in fiddle?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri You nailed it, I really didn't give out the same sets, and the Products in Category=2 is having more than 1 DiscountPercentage resulting error from the function. 
You can post this answer and I'll accept it.

Here's the fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e984c/10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If statement

`where P.AutoID in (SELECT AutoID FROM Product WHERE Category=2)`

fails but

`where P.AutoID in (2910,2912,2820)`

works, then the problem is definitely in function itself, because first statement can not produce mentioned error. I.e. first statement returns different set then second statement and data produces that error probably here:

```
Declare @Price float = (select Price 
                            from Product 
                            where AutoID = @ProductAutoID)
```

and here:

```
(select DiscountPercentage 
         from ProductDiscount 
         where Product_AutoID = @ProductAutoID)
```

Those subqueries are returning more then 1 row, so the error occures.

Answer (score 0):

try this code (i did not check it)-

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id int IDENTITY(1,1),AutoID int)
INSERT INTO @tbl
SELECT AutoID FROM Product WHERE Category=2

DECLARE @x int=1
DECLARE @y int=1

WHILE @x <= (SELECT count (*) from @tbl)
BEGIN
set @y=(select AutoID FROM @tbl WHERE id=@x)
    select MIN(dbo.GetDiscountedPrice(@y))
FROM Product P
SET @x=@x+1
END
```

Comment: I haven't try this out yet as this could involve a huge set of data which putting in a loop might affect its performance

Answer (score 0):

Based on everything you're saying, this should work:

```
select MIN(AutoID)
FROM Product
where Category=2
```

Q: does this work?

```
select GetDiscountedPrice(MIN(AutoID))
FROM Product
where Category=2
```

Q: If not, could you please post "GetDiscountedPrice"?

Comment: the first query did work, but the second didn't. Posted GetDiscountedPrice function

Comment: Thank you for posting "GetDiscountedPrice()".  You'll note that it's a function (returns a single value: the discounted price), and that *IT REQUIRES A SINGLE VALUED INPUT*.  That's probably the reason you're getting the error.  Q: Did you try `select GetDiscountedPrice(MIN(AutoID))` ("MIN" as the inner function, instead of the outer function), as I suggested above?

Comment: Also: is it possible that `AutoID = @ProductAutoID` or `Product_AutoID = @ProductAutoID` might return multiple values?  That, too, could be a problem.

Comment: thanks for the input, but it is not the cause which you can test here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e984c/4/0

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies on the function, because it exists more than 1 DiscountPercentage for a single product. Adding "DISTINCT" in the function when selecting the DiscountPercentage eliminates the duplicate data.

```
    Declare @DP float = ISNULL
    (
        (select DISTINCT DiscountPercentage 
         from ProductDiscount 
         where Product_AutoID = @ProductAutoID), 0)
```